# Raster Calculator QGIS 3.0 , cannot specify output data type

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, qgis-3, format

I am trying to generate a raster layer from the subtraction of a DSM raster layer and a DTM raster layer.
Both my DSM and DTM are in float64 data type. When I run the raster calculator to do the subtraction, I could not specify the data type of the output and the default output that I got was in float32 after subtraction. Is there an option and button to specify the output data type?

I am using QGIS 3.0.

Answer (score 5):

The Raster calculator from the menu toolbar does not have the option to specify the output raster type.

But if you go to the `Raster calculator` from `Processing toolbox -> GDAL -> Raster miscellaneous -> Raster calculator`, it will give you the option to specify the `Output raster type` as you can see below:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately not anymore in 3.6

Comment: @christian.gobel Specifying the output type is still there in both QGIS 3.4.5 and 3.6. Use the `Raster calculator` under the `GDAL -> Raster miscellaneous` not the one under the `Raster analysis`.

Comment: you are right. Thanks. Both tools use the same syntax, with the exception that miscellaneous refer to each layer as A,B...? Right?