# Add viewshed values

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem, viewshed, global-mapper

I have multiple cumulative  viewsheds made with the visibility analysis plugin. I would like to combine them together by adding their pixel values.

In qgis, I can select different pixels and get the derived pixel values but as soon as I blend 2 layers together, export, import and select a pixel, the max value can only be 255.

I have also tried a similar workflow in Global Mapper with similar results.

I'm looking for the resulting file to retain the classifiable data that extends beyond 255. These are complex cumulative view sheds with hundreds of viewpoints that need to retain their raw data.

Comment: Have you tried gdal raster calculator where you can change output data type which should allow values above 256? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280043/raster-calculator-qgis-3-0-cannot-specify-output-data-type

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't showing up in the osgeo shell and didnt realize it could be found in the toolbox